# Message to the user via the bot Telegram

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm going through telegram robot users to send messages .
I have undergone the following message :

> Hi
>   My name is SejiL!

But I have a problem with :

> \n Or /n

Text goes to the next line .
The text for the user to :

> Hi\nMy name is SejiL!
>   Hi/nMy name is SejiL!

Send.

When the text of the original text databases :

> Hi
>   My
>  name is SejiL

The text was sent to the user :

> Hi_My name is SejiL

Please advise Why , thank you

Comment: can you share your source code? What language do you use?

Comment: I am using the PHP language , database problems were solved my problem now use the \ n is

Comment: In PHP prefer using of PHP_EOL constant

Comment: I used the urlencode